# Is it possible to define a static server list with ribbon (via feign) when Eureka is in use?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-ribbon

## Environment

- Spring Boot `1.5.13.RELEASE`
- Spring Cloud `Edgware.SR3`
- Java 8

## Configuration

- Eureka client is enabled and working correctly (I have tested and everything's working as I expect).

Some relevant properties from my configuration:

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=true
service1.ribbon.listOfServers=https://www.google.com
```

## Context

I have an application which speaks to 3 other services using feign clients. Two of these are discovered via Eureka service discovery. These are working well. The final service is an external one with a single static hostname and I do not want this resolved via Eureka. Since I do want Eureka for 2 of these services I would like to keep Eureka enabled.

## Question

For the final service I tried adding `service1.ribbon.listOfServers=https://www.google.com` to the `application.properties`, however this cases the following error at runtime when invoking the feign client:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: Service1Client#test() failed and no fallback available.] with root cause
>   pricing_1            | 
>   pricing_1            | com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: service1
>   pricing_1            |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]

My client is configured as follows:

```
@FeignClient("service1")
public interface Service1Client {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    String test();

}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

## Consideration

Since the spirit of Ribbon as I understand it is to act as a client side load balancer and given in my case there is nothing to load balance (I have one fixed static hostname that returns a single A record in DNS). Ribbon actually feels like an unnecessary component - what I really wanted was the Feign client as I like the fact that it abstracts away the lower level HTTP request and object seralization. So I suppose an alternative follow up question is, can I use feign without ribbon - it seems the nice out of the box behaviour would be to use ribbon - even the Javadoc of the `@FeignClient` annotation says:

> If ribbon is available it will be
>    used to load balance the backend requests, and the load balancer can be configured
>    using a `@RibbonClient` with the same name (i.e. value) as the feign client.

suggesting the two are quite closely related even if they are serving different purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, there are two ways to solve your problem.

**Use Feign without Ribbon**
If you specify `url` attribute in `@FeignClient` annotation, it will work without Ribbon like the below.

```
@FeignClient(name = "service1", url = http://www.google.com)
public interface Service1Client {
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    String test();
}
```

In this case, your other two Feign client will still work with Ribbon and Eureka.

**Use Feign with Ribbon and without Eureka**

What you are missing is in your configuration is `NIWSServerListClassName`.
Its default value is `com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList` and it will use Eureka to retrieve the list of server. If you set `NIWSServerListClassName` to `ConfigurationBasedServerList` for a ribbon client (feign client), only that client will work with `listOfServers` list without retrieving server list from Eureka. And other feign clients will still work with Eureka.

```
service1:
  ribbon:
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
    listOfServers: http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the same using Spring Boot 2.2.x with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer? Specifically how to provide a static list of servers for a given feign client.